# wxPython -- Adding statictext resizes the panel

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, sizer

I have this fairly simple setup of a flexgridsizer creating a 3 x 3 grid:
(quick note for easy reading: pvs = sizers, pvp = panels)

```
    pvs["flex"] = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows = 3, cols = 3, vgap = 0, hgap = 0)
    for index, vert in enumerate(pv.vertNames):
        for horiz in pv.horizNames:
            pvp["{0}_{1}".format(vert, horiz)] = wx.Panel(self)
            pvp["{0}_{1}".format(vert, horiz)].SetBackgroundColour(c.COLORS["black"])

    for panel in pvp.values():
        pvs["flex"].Add(panel, flag = wx.EXPAND)

    proportions = (1, 6, 1)

    for index, prop in enumerate(proportions):
        pvs["flex"].AddGrowableCol(index, prop)
        pvs["flex"].AddGrowableRow(index, prop)

    self.SetSizer(pvs["flex"])
```

I don't explicitly set the size of the panels, they are sized by the growable rows and column proportions.

Later down the way, I add, say, 2 statictexts to the top middle panel:

```
    pvs[me] = {"vert": wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)}
    pvt[me] = {}

    panel.SetForegroundColour(c.COLORS["blue"])
    pvt[me]["title"] = wx.StaticText(panel, label = c.TITLE)
    pvt[me]["title"].SetOwnFont(titleFont)
    pvt[me]["subTitle"] = wx.StaticText(panel, label = c.SUBTITLE)
    pvt[me]["subTitle"].SetOwnFont(subFont)

    pvs[me]["vert"].Add(pvt[me]["title"], flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
    pvs[me]["vert"].Add(pvt[me]["subTitle"], flag = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

    panel.SetSizer(pvs[me]["vert"])
```

Finally to the issue: Adding these statictexts resizes the top middle panel to be significantly wider and taller.  Is there a way to lock a flexgridsizer proportions?  Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong that I can change that will avoid this behavior?

In troubleshooting, I discovered that there is plenty of room for the text to fit in at the original panel size even given the large font size.  I can drop the font size to 5 and it get very tiny but still resizes the panel a tiny bit larger, it's almost like it's pushing its way into the panel instead of just fitting inside.

Comment: Looks interesting but, it's still hard for me to understand exactly the problem. Can you make a minimum example code that reproduces your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @otterb: Thanks for looking.  I was about to make a minimum example when I came up with my own answer that I like.  I posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue I was having is that I was leaving the panels without a size so they were growable based on anything put in them.  So I decided to add explicit sizes but still keep them flexible to different frame sizes by having the sizes created on-the-fly based on percentages:

```
    width = self.package.frame.size[0]
    height = self.package.frame.size[1]
    corner = ((width * .125), (height * .125))
    ns = ((width * .75), (height * .125))
    ew = ((width * .125), (height * .75))
    mid = ((width * .75), (height * .75))
    sizeIter = iter((corner, ns, corner, ew, mid, ew, corner, ns, corner))
```

and then this in the for loop that created the panels:

```
pvp["{0}_{1}".format(vert, horiz)] = wx.Panel(self)
```

changed to:

```
pvp["{0}_{1}".format(vert, horiz)] = wx.Panel(self, size = next(sizeIter))
```

Comment: I see. Then, I wonder if SetSizeHints can help in this situation. You can find more info about it here http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/05/22/wxpython-sizers-tutorial-using-a-gridbagsizer/